# iPhone File system operation questions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to download files from remote to temp folder

the folder on remote like:

```
http://remoteserver.com/abc/def/file1.txt
http://remoteserver.com/abc/file2.png
http://remoteserver.com/abc/pla/mnb/file3.html
```

and the folder structure will like:

```
tmpefolder/abc/def/file1.txt
tmpefolder/abc/file2.png
tmpefolder/abc/pla/mnb/file3.html
```

And then after download, will move files to permanent folder like and keep same folder structure

```
permanentfolder/abc/def/file1.txt
permanentfolder/abc/file2.png
permanentfolder/abc/pla/mnb/file3.html
```

finally remove all files in tempfolder

So my questions are:

1. What the best way to download multi files from server? (Better to show ASIHTTPRequest, it is ok to show me other way)
2. Easy way to create the whole structure of folders? Do I have to split folder path by "/" and check every level path exist and create it?
3. How to copy whole temp folder content to permanent folder? Is it possible to do this with one operation like copy on OS X?
4. Also, like remove operation on OS X, remove temp folder with one shot?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1/ You'd better use `AFNetwork`. `ASIHTTPRequest` is growing old, no longer maintained. `AFNetwork` is more modern, and works with blocks (“hmmm, blocks”, like Homer would say). There are plenty of examples around here, just search.

Specifically, `AFNetwork` allows you to put download operations in a `NSOperationQueue`, that you can handle at your will, let's say, to download 35 files in parallel, with a maximum of 4 running downloads at the same time, and report to you when everything's done.

2, 3, 4/ Take a look at the reference for `NSFileManager`. All you need is there.

Answer (score -1):

create .zip of all your file use following code to download .zip form server.
this will create your folder in NSTemporaryDirectory.

```
 NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/FILENAME.zip",NSTemporaryDirectory()];
 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[obj valueForKey:@"zip_path"]]] attributes:nil];
```

after download move folder to documentDirectory.

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:filePath toPath:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"] error:nil];
```

following code is remove files form temp

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
```